# <VirtualHost *> - это нормально?

Tags: веб-программирование, apache2

Я новичок в настройке веб-сервисов, и сейчас мне нужно настроить Apache для работы трёх разных сайтов на одном ip-адресе. Для этого я решил использовать в `httpd.conf` три директивы `<VirtualHost>` с разными значениями ServerName в них.

Однако, есть два нюанса:

- Виртуальных хостов на машине будет больше в будущем
- Порт доступа для всех сайтов один, и он будет периодически меняться

Из этого следует вывод: если я буду описывать директиву для каждого сайта как `<VirtualHost *:80>`, то при изменении прослушиваемого порта в главном конфиге Apache, придётся менять порт для каждого виртуального хоста.

Из-за этого я решил попробовать прописать `<VirtualHost *>`, и это не вызвало на первый взгляд никаких проблем. Однако в документации и различных статьях об этом я не встречал подобного использования этой директивы. Поэтому у меня возник вопрос - имеет ли смысл и безопасно ли использование такой формы использования `<VirtualHost>` в настройке Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет не имеет, так как вас интересует лишь `Apache` который висит на 80ом порту. Директива `<VirtualHost *:80>` позволяет прослушывать все хосты на 80ом порту. Используя `<VirtualHost *>` вы как бы слушаете все хосты на всех портах (вам ведь это не нужно?). Простой способ иметь много виртуалок это

```
#первая виртуалка

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName YOUR_WEB_SERVICE_NAME.dev
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/YOUR_WEB_SERVICE
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/YOUR_WEB_SERVICE.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/YOUR_WEB_SERVICE.log combined
<Directory "/var/www/html/YOUR_WEB_SERVICE">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#вторая виртуалка

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName ANOTHER_WEB_SERVICE_NAME.dev
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ANOTHER_WEB_SERVICE
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ANOTHER_WEB_SERVICE.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ANOTHER_WEB_SERVICE.log combined
<Directory "/var/www/html/ANOTHER_WEB_SERVICE">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

и так для каждой последующей виртуалки, изменяя `ServerName`, `DocumentRoot` ну и логи соответственно. На линукс в папке `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` есть файлик `000-default.conf`. Туда можно хосты прописывать. Также можно делать разные `.conf` файлы для удобства.

Comment: Я понимаю, но проблема в том, что в будущем я буду несколько раз менять порт, на котором висит апач и все виртуалки соответственно. Насколько я понял, в вашем примере для смены порта придётся менять и порты всех виртуалок. Я ищу способ этого избежать.

Comment: Eсть regular expression для таких случаев. Открываем `Notepad++` нажимаем `Ctrl+H` и вставляем `\*\:80` заменить на  `*:81` или любой другой порт.